# Communicating over socket.io with a heroku app

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I have two applications that need to communicate with each other. One is a node app deployed on heroku. The other is a node app deployed on a raspberry pi3. I need the raspberry pi3 to send the heroku app data using socket.io

On the heroku app I have

```
http.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
    console.log("listening on *:" + process.env.PORT);
});
```

Which listens on the port Heroku assigns.

On the raspberry pi app I have :

```
let socket = io(`http://appName.herokuapp.com:7256`)
```

I logged out the port number from heroku when it connected and it was 7256. However, I am unable to communicate with the application on Heroku. There are not any errors when I am trying to emit from the pi. But the Heroku app isn't receiving anything. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use port 80 (or no port at all, to default to 80).

The `PORT` env var is an internal port - it's the port within the Heroku container that your app should listen on.

Externally, Heroku's routers expose your app online at the normal ports: 80 and 443 (http and https).